# Button link doesn't work in Firefox, IE

Tags: html

I have  links inside of  that work fine in Chrome, but not IE or Firefox. Nothing happens if you click on them. I've messed with the CSS (z-index included), but am out of ideas. This is XHTML coming out of Drupal.

The html looks like this:

```
<div class="product-display-block-link">
  <button>
    <a href="/checkout/outfield-banner/1">Add to cart</a>
  </button>
</div>
```

Any suggestions for where I can look?

Comment: I'd suspect the path in your href. Is checkout in the same folder?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The HMTL syntax does not allow an `a` element within a `button` element, so it is not surprising that it does not work across browsers. There should be no reason to use such a construct, since you can either style a link to look like a button or associate an action with a button, depending on what you wish to accomplish.

Comment: "or associate an action with a button" - can you please give an example?

Comment: Example: `<button onclick="window.location='/checkout/outfield-banner/1'">Add to cart</button>`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a button (i.e. a thing to submit a form with or dangle JavaScript from), use a button. If you want a link, use a link. If you want a link that looks like a button, use a link then style it to look the way you want.

You can't mix the two because `<button>` elements aren't allowed to contain `<a>` elements. The [definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html#a_dtd_XHTML-1.0-Strict) of the element explicitly excludes them:

```
<!--
 Content is %Flow; excluding a, form and form controls
--> 
<!ELEMENT button %button.content;>  <!-- push button -->

<!ENTITY % button.content
   "(#PCDATA | p | %heading; | div | %lists; | %blocktext; |
    table | %special; | %fontstyle; | %phrase; | %misc;)*">
```

Comment: This is also true [in HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-button-element.html), not just XHTML1.0.

Comment: It is true in every version of (X)HTML. I just referenced XHTML 1.0 since the question mentioned XHTML.

Answer (score 2):

`<button>` isn't being used right.

HTML:

```
 <div class="product-display-block-link">
    <button onClick="javascript: window.location='/checkout/outfield-banner/1'">Add to Cart</button>
</div>
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/s8jtf/

Comment: Not sure why you were down voted, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation and posted my question here => [Why does Dreamweaver cc16, Bootstrap v3.3.6, created, hyperlinked Button work in Opera & Chrome but not IE or Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50786927/why-does-dreamweaver-cc16-bootstrap-v3-3-6-created-hyperlinked-button-work-in/50826352#50826352)

Here is my original code for a Button =>

```
The Button html code is: =>
```

`<div align="center" style="font-size: 1.5em">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg">
       <a href="https://howtoliveoffthegridnow.com/wordpress/get-your-own-off-the-grid-checklist/" title="Access option to download checklist"><strong>FREE: 11 Things To Know Before Going Off The Grid</strong></a>
    </button>
</div>`

and the relevant bootstrap.css v3.3.6 is linked conventionally using: =>

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" />`

That worked in Chrome and Opera but not IE or Firefox though, apparently, it should not have worked in any browser.

Here is what I changed that Button code element into =>

```
`<div class="btn btn-lg" style="background-color:#ffffff;">
 <a href="https://howtoliveoffthegridnow.com/wordpress/get-your-own-off-the-grid-checklist/" title="Access option to download checklist"><strong>FREE: 11 Things To Know Before Going Off The Grid</strong></a>
```

That works across all browser. /psb

Answer (score -1):

Also, type attribute is missing. Different browsers assume different type, for example, not necessarily type="submit".

Comment: The Submit state is the [default state of a `<button>`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-button-element.html#attr-button-type).

Comment: If the browser doesn't assume submit, then it is broken. This probably isn't relavent anyway since there doesn't appear to be a form involved.

Comment: Unfortunately, differences in browsers are to be taken into account. As for submit not relevant, I was thinking the form could be one of the solutions as it works without javascript (which could be relevant or not, of course).