# popup jquery doesn"t show anything- firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using popup in my html page.

my button element:

```
<button class="show-detail"><a href="#popup1">show details</a></button>
```

my popup dialog:

```
                           <div id="popup1" class="overlay">
                                <div class="popup">
                                    <h2>test </h2>
                                    <a class="close" href="#table">&times;</a>
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <img src="assets/main/img/pepsi.png">
                                        <a href="company.html">test </a>
                                     <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                         <li class="info"><span class="fa fa-check"></span><span class="pr10">test </span><span>test </span></li>
                                         <li class="info"><span class="fa fa-check"></span><span class="pr10">test </span><span>test </span></li>
                                         <li class="info"><span class="fa fa-check"></span><span class="pr10">test </span><span>test </span></li>
                                         <li class="info"><span class="fa fa-check"></span><span class="pr10">test </span><span>test  </span></li>
                                     </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

my chrome browser works fine but Firefox doesn't show anything.
I think everything is ok. where is my problem?

Comment: Refer to this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772520/button-link-doesnt-work-in-firefox-ie. And make your button tag like this - <a href="#popup1"><button class="show-detail">show details</button></a> . It will work.

Comment: unfortunately, I couldn't get the related answer.